# Challenging series evaluation

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

We have
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(nk+1)^2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(nk+n-1)^2}$$
I encountered this series while evaluating an integral, and it  seems to have a nice closed form for each $n$. Here are the first few values by WolframAlpha:
$$S(2)=0 \hspace{2cm} S(3)=-\frac{2\pi^2}{27} \hspace{2cm} S(4)=-\frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2}\hspace{2cm} S(5)=-\frac{(5+3\sqrt5)\pi^2}{125} \dots$$
After checking the first few [cases](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Blogx%2CPower%5Bx%2C11%5D%2B1%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cinf%7D%5D), I conjectured that the result is:
$$S(n)=-\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$
but couldn't prove it.
I managed to compute by myself only $S(2)$, which is trivial of course, and $S(3)$, which can be obtained by some simple manipulations using Dirichlet $\eta$ function, but when I tackled the general problem this approach didn't help me.

The integral I was trying to solve is $$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{1+x^n}dx$$ and I managed to prove that
$$I=S(n)$$ so this is where the idea came from. Please, don't answer with other evaluations of the integral which could prove the conjectured result, I am asking for an evaluation that starts off from the series, as if you didn't know it is related to the integral at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The partial fraction expansion for the cotangent could be useful

Comment: Mathematica does verify your conjectured result, so you're on the right track.

Comment: If you compare the series and the integral, you will find the convergent ranges for the parameter $n$ are different. For series, it converges for $n\neq \frac{1}q, ~q\in \mathbb{Z}$. But for integral, it converges for $n>1$. So maybe you make some mistakes when do the series expansion, i.e. expand the integrand outside its convergent radius.

Comment: @MathFail thank you for letting me know, it is probably because when I do integrals I can't care less if it's legit to exchange sum and integral, or limit and integral, and stuff like that, I just try to get to a result and then check if it's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s consider the function
$$ T(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{n k+x}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{n k+n-x}
$$
Rearranging $n$ and re-indexing $k$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
T(x)&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac{x}{n}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1-\frac{x}{n}} \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac{x}{n}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{-k+\frac{x}{n}} \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac{x}{n}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the property for $x\not\in Z,$
$$\pi \csc (\pi x)=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=-N}^N \frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}, $$
we have
$$T(x)=\frac{\pi}{n} \csc \left(\frac{\pi x}{n}\right)
$$

Differentiating both sides and putting $x=1$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(n) & =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(n k+1)^2}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(n k+n-1)^2} =-\frac{\pi^2}{n^2} \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Nice, this is the Mittag-Leffler's theorem for expansion at poles for $\csc(\beta x)$.

Answer (score 5):

$$S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(nk+1)^2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(nk+n-1)^2}$$
Using the Hurwitz zeta function (we could also use the polygamma function)
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(nk+1)^2}=\frac{\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 n}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,\frac{1}{2 n}\right)}{4 n^2}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(nk+n-1)^2}=\frac{\zeta \left(2,1-\frac{1}{2 n}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 n}\right)}{4 n^2}$$
$$S(n)=\frac 1{4 n^2} \left(\zeta \left(2,\frac{n-1}{2 n}\right)+\zeta   \left(2,\frac{n+1}{2 n}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{2n-1}{2 n}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{2
   n}\right)\right)$$ Simplifying
$$S(n)=\frac{\pi ^2}{4 n^2}\left(\sec ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)-\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)\right)$$

Using the double angle formulae, then your result.

Comment: Nice one, thank you. I accepted the other answer because it uses tools I already know, but now I'm motivated to learn more about Hurwitz Zeta function.

Comment: @Zima. The same can be done with the polygamma function

Comment: As soon as I saw those series I was thinking zeta functions. (+1)

Comment: Interestingly, it’s this closed form that Mathematica obtains rather than the simplified double-angle result. That probably says something about how Mathematica handles such infinite sums.

Answer (score 0):

> $$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{1+x^n}dx$$

Consider

$$J=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{1+x^n}dx,~~~I=\frac{dJ}{da}|_{a=0}$$

Let $t=x^n$

$$\begin{align} J&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{1+x^n}dx=\frac{1}n \int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\frac{1+a}{n}-1}}{1+t}dt=\frac{1}nB(z_1, 1-z_1)=\frac{\pi}{n\sin(\pi z_1)}
\end{align}$$

where $z_1=\frac{1+a}{n}$

$$I=\frac{dJ}{da}|_{a=0}=\frac{d}{da}\frac{\pi}{n\sin( \frac{\pi(1+a)}{n})}|_{a=0}=-\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I asked for.